# Translation function with optional substitution arguments

Tags: php, internationalization

I have a function `L($key)` that translates my strings.

Nothing fancy:

```
$_langs = include(__DIR__ . '/lang.php');
function L($key)
{
    global $_langs;

    if (array_key_exists($key, $_langs)) {
        return $_langs[$key];
    } else {
        return $key;
    }
}
```

When I need parametrized translation (with `%s`), I use this:

```
sprintf(L('myKey'), $var)
```

Is there some easy way to make it so I can use just `L('myKey', $var)`?

I thought of adding `array $params=null` as a formal parameter (It'd then take array as second argument), but how can I then expand it to individual arguments of `sprintf()`?

Comment: if you are going to use an array you could do something like `L( 'myKey', array('varname1'=>$var1, 'varname2' =>$var2)`. Not so sure it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, I've figured it out right after asking ^^

Here's my solution - if you can write it better, feel free to answer and I can accept it.

```
// i18n utility
$_langs = include(__DIR__ . '/lang.php');
function L($key)
{
    global $_langs;
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_langs)) {
        $formats = array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
        $sprintf_args = array_merge([$_langs[$key]], $formats);
        return call_user_func_array('sprintf', $sprintf_args);
    } else {
        return $key;
    }
}
```